# XPath of CData Content

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following log in XML:

```
<log level="INFO">
    <msg><![CDATA[Method=GET URL=http://test.com:80/de?OP=gt&Reset=1(Clat=[430883619],Clon=[-1161273073],Accept=*/*)Result(Content-Encoding=[gzip], Content-Length=[3017], ntCoent-Length=[6385], Content-Type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8]) Status=200 Times=TISP:1936/CSI:-/Me:0/Total:1936]]>
    </msg>
</log>
```

Now, I would like to access to Clat=[430883619] and Clon=[-1161273073] with XPath.
I know that I can use:

```
/log/msg/text()
```

But I would only get whole CDATA. I also tried some xPATH generators, but they were not very helpful.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't believe XPath parses into CDATA ...

Comment: CDATA sections are just an alternative way of expressing a text node. Extract that text, then run xpath over it. Or write/find an extension function that will assist with this.

Comment: You could play around with [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)

Comment: another solution would be to use the [substring functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) like `substring-before(substring-after(/log/msg/text(), '('), ',Accept')`